# Create Table with pay grades

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

Having trouble coding for the following question:

"Create a table that has 15 pay grades (rows) and within each pay grade are 10 steps (columns). Grade 1 step 1 starts at $21,885. Each step in a pay grade increases by 1.4 percent from the previous step. Each pay grade increases by 4.3 percent from step 1 in the previous grade. Label each row and column appropriately. Print the table and write to a file. Use integer values only."

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please include the code you have written already, and any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do your homework for you, but I'll give you some ideas to point you in the right direction. I assume you can use numpy so you can create and use arrays (perfect for this application).

1. Create a numpy ndarray, dimension: 15 rows (pay grades) by 10 columns
   (steps)
2. Assign the starting pay for Grade 1, Step 1 to cell [0,0]
3. Step/Column values increase by 1.4% so the next column value iscol_i+1 = 1.014*col_i
4. Grade/Rows values increase by 4.3% so the next row value is row_i+1 = 1.043*row_i

These can be calculated with 2 loops over the row/column indices.
If you're clever, you can create values for one row (or column) then calculate each row/comun in one shot.
ndarray won't handle mixed data types for titles, but printing should be simple enough with formatted strings.

"Use integer values only" leads to an interesting question:
Do you use integer math, or retain accuracy with floats, then print integer values?
Also, you need to decide if you want to truncate or round.